# Getting data during play. OpenAL

Tags: sdl, openal, graphic

Is it possible to get sound data during playing in OpenAl? For example: I generate white noise and I want to present this in graphically in chart amplitude and frequency. So I want to get which part of sound actually is playing and use it with SDL for example.